# Edit new document choices under projects.

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document

When a person goes a project library and creates project document library they have an option to create a new document when the end user clicks "new". It displays a list of document types to choose from. Where can this be edited?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Library Settings" look for "ContentType" section. if not do this `Library Settings->Advanced Settings->Choose 'Yes' to Allow management of content types?` and save.

Now, in Library Settings you will see a new section called 'Content Type' in that select this option to change the 'order' or 'Visible' of your choice.
[image]

> **Note**: If you want to have template for each document type refer [here](https://wpoffice365.com/using-document-templates-with-lists-and-content-types-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: OK I did this but that updates the "New" button on the site page. Not the new button on the subsite "projects" page. that's what I need to update. how do you update that?

Comment: why is this so hard to find and there is NO documentation on it? Microsoft drives me nuts with this bogus. I'm essentially trying to edit a document set's choices to make "new" documents. where are the content types for that?

Comment: What you mean by `new button on the subsite "projects" page` are you referring to custom link. if so edit the link to point the respective content type...